# Register new dynamically created element with existing function, in javascript

Tags: javascript, listener

I have created a new html element, and inserted it onto a node. However it doesn't have any listeners registered on the class name 'edit-expense-category' because of this. My code for registering this class name on page load is as follows:

```
$(".edit-expense-category").click(function () { 
  // function related stuff
});
```

What I'd like to know is once I have another element created dynamically using the class name above, how do I register this element with a listener as well?

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest you using jQuery's `.live`, but it turns out it is deprecated. However, the newer equivalent is `.on`. Use it like this:

```
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );  

// In your specific case it'll look like:
$( document ).on( "click", ".edit-expense-category", { }, function () {
    // function related stuff
});
```

More about this [here](https://api.jquery.com/live/) (don't forget to look into the newer equivalent of [.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/))

Comment: Thanks, I had to use .live - the framework that I've been given to work with is so ancient that it Js version doesn't support .on :(